# Why is the movie titled "The Sixth Sense"?

Tags: title, the-sixth-sense

What is the relevance of the title to the story?
Is the ability to talk to the ghost referred as the sixth sense?

Comment: Why would anyone downvote this question? Why would it get two downvotes?

Comment: It's a good question. I gave it an upvote!

Comment: @Evik most likely because "sixth sense" is a simple phrase that can be looked up in 10 seconds...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

["Sixth sense" on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sixth_sense_%28disambiguation%29#In_senses).

Humans have five traditionally recognized physiological senses (sight, hearing, smell, touch, taste). Thus, "sixth sense" usually refers to something that goes beyond physiological perception (e.g. extrasensorical abilities).

[Traditional senses on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sense#Traditional_senses)

Comment: Good answer! Just to expand a little, there is a technical name for it: ESP extra sensory perception. Here's the wiki link. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extrasensory_perception